# ¿Como sumar los valores por indice de cada arreglo con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

En una petición hacia el servidor me retorna los siguientes arreglos

```
[6,8]
[2,9]
[4,1]
[5,6]
```

La idea es que me sume por indices es decir que el resultado deberia de ser `[17,24]`

> He intentado recorrerlo con un for de la siguiente manera:

```
                    var sum = [];
                    for(var d = 0; d < dataGraphic.length; d++){
                        for (var p = 0; p < dataGraphic[d]['data'].length; p++) {

                            sum[p] += dataGraphic[d]['data'][p];
                        }

                    }
```

pero me arroja la consola **[NaN, Nan]**...
¿Por que sucede esto?, ¿Que estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: Deberias mostrar la estructura completa que retorna el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

No se de donde sale el indice `data` pero tu problema es que no estas inicializando el array `sum`.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var dataGraphic = [[6,8],
[2,9],
[4,1],
[5,6]];

var sum = [0,0];
for(var d = 0; d < dataGraphic.length; d++){
  for (var p = 0; p < dataGraphic[d].length; p++) {
    sum[p] += dataGraphic[d][p];
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una alternativa con las array.prototypes [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) y [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
let dataGraphic = [
  [6,8],
  [2,9],
  [4,1],
  [5,6]
];

sum = dataGraphic.reduce(function (a, c) {
    c.forEach(function (b, i) {       
        a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + b;
    });
    return a;
});

console.log(sum);
```